# The fastest way to perform a click in Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, dom, swt

I used SWT Browser in my Java project.

I get content of page by JavaScript, next get button which I need to perform to click by Java code.

Now I do this from Java code like below:

```
browser.execute("document.getElementById('actionButton').click();");
```

`browser` is object from lib `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;`

But I am not sure that is the fastest way to click. I care as soon as possible to click on button.

Is there any fastest way to perform click on button ?

Away from graphic click, maybe by fire event ?

I'm comparing it by example when I call method `buttonComponent.doClick();` on button in Java it cost about 100ms (by graphics thread and do click on button) and when I used `buttonComponent.getActionListeners()[0].actionPerformed(null);` it cost 0ms !

Comment: Why do you "need" to click it with Java code?  If you're generating a button in Javascript and want it clicked as soon as possible then simply click it as soon as it's generated.

Comment: I load page where button exist. I want to click this button from my desktop Java app by fastest way.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with your current attempt.

Comment: I am no t sure that is the fastest way. Like in java desktop app when I get button component and call `buttonComponent.doClick();` on them it take about 100ms (graphics thread) but when I call `buttonComponent.getActionListeners()[0].actionPerformed(null);` it cost 0ms

Comment: @czArek Why is this operation so time critical? What exactly are you doing? Is the code you've got just now not good enough?

Comment: I ask question 'is there any fastest way to do click?' because I think that it can be similar to my java desktop problem and I cant check this on page (do not have access to page methods)

Comment: @czArek I'd recomment to just go with `click()`. You're analogy with the Swing listener is flawed, because it's not as easy as you make it out to be. What if there's no action listener at all; by passing `null` you loose information, etc. I don't think the gain in performance balances out the downsides. Same will be the case for JavaScript.

Comment: This answer expected what I need to know. Thanks @Baz !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recomment to just go with `click()`.

You're analogy with the Swing listener is flawed, because it's not as easy as you make it out to be:

1. What if there's no action listener at all?
2. By passing null you loose information, etc.

I don't think the gain in performance balances out the downsides.

The same will be the case for Javascript. There are too many things that can go wrong by trying to invoke listeners (if exist) manually and the performance improvement (if any) you get from it isn't that great either.